# retrieving video information and link to mp4

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any documentation about the http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXX ?

Since a week or so it seems I do not get correct information anymore. I am using the `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` property in the response stream to get the url for the video link of the mp4 type of my video. But this property is now returning an empty value.

Has something been changed in the `get_video_info` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_video_info` endpoint is not, and has never been, a supported public API.

If you'd like to play back YouTube content, you need to use one of the official YouTube Players:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#player_apis